# Assigning a function call to a variable in a recursion results in different output

Tags: c, recursion

Below are two similar examples that define a recursive function which will print the digits of a number that are smaller than 5  while also counting them.

> Input: 12345
>   Output: 1234  : 4         //There are 4 digits smaller than 5

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

int function(int n) {
    if(!n) return 0;

    int r = function(n/10); 

    if ((n%10) < 5) {
        printf("%d", n%10);
        return r+1;
    }
    else return r;
}

int main() {
    int  x;

    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf(" : %d\n", function(x));

    return 0;
}
```

---

---

Second code which has the same functionality, ***but prints everything in reverse that I cannot seem to understand.*** I am not fluid in programming and still new to it so I hope the question is clearly stated.

> Input: 12345
>   Output: 4321: 4

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

int function(int n) {
    if(!n) return 0;

    if(n%10<5) {
        printf("%d", n%10);
        return function(n/10)+1;
    }
    return function(n/10);
}

int main() {
    int x;

    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf(" : %d\n", function(x));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Compare the two codes.  What do they do differently?  Since your question is related to the order of the output data, pay especial attention to the order of operations.  Hint: assigning the function result to a variable does not, in itself, have anything to do with it.  It wouldn't be hard to rewrite the second code to do that, too, without changing its observable behavior.

Comment: Try working it out with a pencil and a piece of paper. What happens when youcall function(12345) ? For case 2, it fails the n%10<5 test, so it next calls function(1234). that passes the test, so it prints "4". And so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In first example you call function before printing, so calls and prints happen in this order:

```
call function(12345)
> call function(1234)
>> call function(123)
>>> call function(12)
>>>> call function(1)
>>>>> call function(0)
>>>>>> immediate return
>>>>> print 1
>>>> print 2
>>> print 3
>> print 4
> no print
```

In second example you print first and then call function, so order is:

```
call function(12345)
> no print
> call function(1234)
>> print 4
>> call function(123)
>>> print 3
>>> call function(12)
>>>> print 2
>>>> call function(1)
>>>>> print 1
>>>>> call function(0)
>>>>>> immediate return
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if I like to deal with recursions, I sometimes still have difficulty in. In   `int r = function(n/10);` , your function goes until knock against `0`. When knocked, because of stack structure, numbers comes 1-2-3-4-5 in that order. (Look LIFO). In this order process going print 1-2-3-4-5. For second code, after checking `if(n%10<5)` you are already running  first `printf("%d", n%10);` so it begins with 5-4-3-2-1 then runnig `function(n/10)+1;` so it again divides `1234 / 10`, `123/10`, `....` in process until knock against `0`. IMHO, recursion can be better understood, if one gets stack structure well.